# Retrieving or streaming all history with Firefox Web-Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, history, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying retrieve the entire available history using [`browser.history.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/search). The [example provided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/search#Examples) by Mozilla doesn't work since the default maximum number of results is 100.

I thought I could stream the history over multiple searches by passing on the last batch's earliest found date as the upper limit for the next search.

```
async function getHistory() {
  const query = { text: '', startTime: 0 }
  const results = [];
  let response;
  while ((response = await browser.history.search(query)).length > 0) {
    results.concat(response);
    query.endTime = response[response.length-1].lastVisitTime - 1;
  }
  return results;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as the search returned items with a `lastVisitTime` greater than the `endTime` passed to the query object, which is not what I got from the documentation.

An alternative I found was passing the largest possible value to `maxResults` which is <strike>2<sup>53</sup>-1</strike> 2<sup>52</sup>. I'd rather not do this since I want to stream the data in more manageable chunks.

What am I doing wrong with the first method? How can I stream blocks of adjacent history entries down to the end?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this, the issue was with the MDN documentation. It originally stated for `endTime` that "If it is supplied, this option excludes results whose `lastVisitTime` is later than this time". In practice, `endTime` applied to **any** visit, and after filing [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1525135), the documentation was corrected.

It looks like there isn't a way to iteratively get time-adjacent chunks of `VisitItem`s from the web extensions API. You can work around this by using the oldest result's `lastVisitTime` as the `startTime` for the next chunk, and discard any visits past that.

This means a bit of overhead, but I doubt this will ever be solved in the current browser generation because, Chrome, as the dominant browser already has a good history viewer and Firefox history add-ons aren't in high demand.

[This bug](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5394843094220800#) also has a good description of the problem, and why the developers chose to implement the history search in this way.